How to prove this system is not causal?

I set $x_1(t)=0$ and use the final rest property to get $y_1(t)=0$, and $y_2(t)=0$ for $t>1$. However, I cannot find general $y_2(t)$ for $x_2(t)$.

Hi, welcome to DSP.SE  Complete answers to HW questions are not allowed on DSP.SE. Please show the work you have done so far...
